# Ktor Resources type-safe routing plugin to generate URLs and paths

Tags: kotlin, routes, url-routing, ktor

I have recently updated current Ktor version to 2.1.x and Locations plugin is now deprecated. I'm refactoring code to use [Resources plugin for type-safe routing](https://ktor.io/docs/type-safe-routing.html). The documentation is lacking how to generate paths from Resources objects. I'm trying to create a redirect address based on a Resource and achieve a functionality like in [Locations plugin to build URLs](https://ktor.io/docs/locations.html)

```
val path = application.locations.href(Listing(name = "movies", page = 10, count = 20))
```

### Resource definition

```
@Serializable
@Resource("clients")
class Clients() {
    @Serializable
    @Resource("{clientID}")
    class ID(val parent: Clients, val clientID: Int) {}
}
```

### Route definition

```
fun Route.clientRouting(dao: ClientDao) {
    route("") {
        get<Clients> {
            call.respondText("Hello Client!")
        }

        get<Clients.ID> { clientID ->
            call.respondRedirect(...) //Redirect to Clients route
        }
    }
}
```

So... Is there a standard way of generating paths and URLs from Resources?

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `href` method on an `Application` instance to get a URL for a specified resource:

```
get<Clients.ID> { clientID ->
    call.respondRedirect(call.application.href(Clients()))
}
```

Comment: It worked smoothly, thanks @aleksei. Is there any other way without requiring access to call object? I'm trying to understand why there is dependency on the call itself.

Comment: You need to have a reference to an instance of the `Application` or a reference to the `Resources` plugin at least: `href(call.application.plugin(Resources).resourcesFormat, Clients())`